# cakephp lot of queries inside a query

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp

I have a site developed in cakephp 2.x
I have a query with contain with a very lot of table relationed. I know that the most efficient way to do this big query is to make the join query manually. But I wanted to try with contain. I have selected only the field that I need but at the end I print how much queries inside are created: 5000 queries!! The database take 6-10 second to elaborate this query and I want to optimize time. Has cakephp a method to optimize? I don't want to use join now because there are a lot of join to create. Is possible? I know that is a crazy query with a lot of data but is the main page of the product with a lot of data.
This is the query:

```
$this->set('product',$this->Product->find('all', array(
                    'contain' => array(
                            'Origin'  => array(
                                'fields'=>array('id','diet_id'),
                                'OriginAlias' => array(
                                    'fields'=>array('id','origin_id','language','alias'),
                                    'conditions' =>  array('OriginAlias.language' => $lang)
                                ),
                                'Diet' => array(
                                    'fields'=>array('id'),
                                    'DietAlias' => array(
                                        'fields'=>array('id','diet_id','language','alias'),
                                        'conditions' =>  array('DietAlias.language' => $lang)
                                    ),
                                )
                            ),
                            'ProductAlias' => array(
                                    'conditions' =>  array('ProductAlias.alias' => $alias),
                                    'User' => array(
                                        'fields'=>array('id','username'),
                                        'Profile' => array(
                                            'fields'=>array('id','user_id','country','sex','diet','show_diet'),
                                        ),
                                        'UserOptions' => array ('fields' => array ('avatar_type')),
                                        'Avatar' => array ('fields' => array ('filename'))
                                    ),
                                    'User2' => array(
                                        'fields'=>array('id','username'),
                                        'Profile' => array(
                                            'fields'=>array('id','user_id','country','sex','diet','show_diet'),
                                        ),
                                        'UserOptions' => array ('fields' => array ('avatar_type')),
                                        'Avatar' => array ('fields' => array ('filename'))
                                    )
                            ),
                            'ProductImage'=> array(
                                'limit' => 1,

                                'ProductImageVote'=> array(
                                    'order' => 'ProductImageVote.vote desc'
                                ),
                                'User' => array(
                                    'fields'=>array('id','username'),
                                        'Profile' => array(
                                            'fields'=>array('id','user_id','country','sex','diet','show_diet'),
                                        ),
                                )
                            ),
                            'ProductGroupProduct' => array(
                                'fields'=>array('id','user_id','product_id','product_group_id'),
                                'ProductGroup'=> array(
                                            'fields'=>array('id','text','language'),
                                        ),
                            ),
                            'ProductIngredientVersion' => array(
                                'conditions' =>  $cond_version,
                                'limit' => 1,
                                'ProductIngredient' => array(
                                    /*'Product' => array(
                                        'ProductAlias' => array()
                                    ),*/
                                    'Ingredient' => array(
                                        'fields'=>array('id','user_id','origin_id','active'),
                                        'IngredientAlias' => array(
                                            'fields'=>array('id','user_id','ingredient_id','edit_user_id','alias'),
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                            'ProductVersion' => array(
                                'conditions' =>  array('ProductVersion.active' => '1', 'ProductVersion.product_id' => $id),
                                'limit' => 1,
                                'ProductProperty' => array(
                                    'Property' => array(
                                        'fields'=>array('id','user_id','group_id','unit_id'),
                                        'PropertyAlias'  => array(
                                            'fields'=>array('id','user_id','property_id','alias','language'),
                                            'conditions' =>  array('PropertyAlias.language' => $lang)
                                        ),
                                        'Unit' => array(
                                            'fields'=>array('id','user_id','symbol','active'),
                                        ),
                                        'PropertyGroup' => array(
                                            'fields'=>array('id','user_id'),
                                            'PropertyGroupAlias'  => array(
                                                'fields'=>array('id','user_id','group_id','alias'),
                                                'conditions' =>  array('PropertyGroupAlias.language' => $lang)
                                            )
                                        )
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                            'Manufacturer' => array(
                                            'fields'=>array('id','text'),
                                        ),
                            'Brand' => array(
                                            'fields'=>array('id','text'),
                                        ),
                            'UserProductLike' => array(
                                'conditions' =>  array('UserProductLike.product_id' => $id),
                            ),
                            'UserProductHate' => array(
                                'conditions' =>  array('UserProductHate.product_id' => $id),
                            ),
                        ),
                    'conditions' => array('Product.id' => $id)  
                )));
```

Comment: as you can see containable is not panacea. Especially with relations where you search for children of the record it create different query for each record. So the advise of creating manually sql or view is not bad idea. I would do it this way.

Comment: ok How can I write a big query like this? @NikChankov

Comment: It's not impossible, but it should be done from someone with strong DB background and most important - knowing the application logic. As extra you could save the query as View and then access it as normal SQL table.