# SQL join into join create a good array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, join, left-join

Hi  I want to make a good query to have a good array. Now for example I have this query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM products 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  product_aliases 
        ON product_aliases.product_id = products.id 
        AND product_aliases.alias = '$alias'
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (product_images
            LEFT OUTER JOIN  product_image_votes 
                    ON product_image_votes.product_image_id = product_images.id)
        ON product_images.product_id = products.id 
WHERE products.id = $id
```

The result is two array like this:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'products' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'user_id' => '1',

    ),
    'product_aliases' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'product_id' => '1',
        'language' => 'it',
    ),
    'product_images' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'product_id' => '1',
    ),
    'product_image_votes' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'product_image_id' => '1',
        'vote' => '1',
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'products' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'user_id' => '1',

    ),
    'product_aliases' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'product_id' => '1',
        'language' => 'it',
    ),
    'product_images' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'product_id' => '1',
    ),
    'product_image_votes' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'product_image_id' => '1',
        'vote' => '1',
    )
)
```

The problem is that: I want only  a unique array that contain product and for example product_images that contain in an array product_images_votes.
The first problem is:

- have a unique array and not two arrays
- create array inside array in base of my left join annidate

Example of array:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'products' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'user_id' => '1',

    ),
    'product_aliases' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'product_id' => '1',
        'language' => 'it',
    ),
    'product_images' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'product_id' => '1',
        array('product_image_votes' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'product_image_id' => '1',
            'vote' => '1',
        ))
    )
```

Is possible to do ?
I'm working with php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is good as it is, but you need to construct the nesting in PHP. You cannot really produce nested structures in SQL alone so you must work with the flattened structure as you have it.

This can be done with some creative looping. Create an output array which is indexed by `products['id']`. On each iteration, create a new entry if it does not already exist. If it does exist, add to its `product_images`, an array also indexed by `product_images['id']`.

```
// To hold the final array
$output = array();
foreach ($original_array as $row) {

  // Storing these id values to make them easier to refer to...
  $id = $row['products']['id'];
  $pid = $row['product_images']['id'];
  $paid = $row['product_aliases']['id'];
  $pivid = $row['product_image_votes']['id'];

  // Create the product entry if it does not exist
  // and initialize arrays for product_images and product_aliases    
  if (!isset($output[$id])) {
    $output[$id] = array(
      'products' => $row['products'],
      // Initialize these to sub-arrays containing the first ones from this row
      // using the id as the array key
      'product_aliases' => array($paid => $row['product_aliases']),
      'product_images' => array($pid => $row['product_images'])
    );
    // Then add the first vote
    $output[$id]['product_images'][$pid]['product_image_votes'] = array();
    $output[$id]['product_images'][$pid]['product_image_votes'][$pivid] = $row['product_image_votes'];
  }
  // If it does exist already, append the alias if that does not exist, the image, the vote etc.
  else {
    // First add the alias if not already set
    if (!isset($output[$id]['product_aliases'][$paid])) {
      $output[$id]['product_aliases'][$paid] = $row['product_aliases'];
    }
    // Then add the image if not already set
    if (!isset($output[$id]['product_images'][$pid])) {
      $output[$id]['product_images'][$pid] = $row['product_images'];
    }
    // And nest in the image_votes
    if (!isset($output[$id]['product_images'][$pid]['product_image_votes'][$pivid])) {
      $output[$id]['product_images'][$pid]['product_image_votes'][$pivid] = $row['product_image_votes'];
    }
  }
}
```

There's a lot here, and it is likely I have syntax errors or missing `]` somewhere. Good luck with it.

Comment: no problem for syntax errors, think that into my query I have a lot of join, I have count the table to join into my query: 40 tables to parse.. OMG.. I thinked that there is a method or something to help me instead of parse all the results

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri Well, this is where ORM's or frameworks like CakePHP are useful. The table relationships are defined in the object model, then you retrieve a product for example and just call methods to get its associated images, etc.  Without a framework you have to do a lot of the work manually.

Comment: This query is done into cakephp but I have too many contain and make 5000 queries.  After this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487038/cakephp-lot-of-queries-inside-a-query I decide to write the query manually

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri That is the trade-off then. The framework generates a lot of queries and is slow, or you build one fast query and must parse the results yourself.

Comment: Is an hard choise, but I think that build the query manually is more efficient. But with 40 tables to join I'll spend a lot of time to parse It. But if this is the only way I have to done it

Comment: but is possible to have only one array instead of multiple array?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri What multiple arrays? `$output` will be one array and it is indexed by products.id.

Comment: yes if is possible I want only an array because now I have the same products.id but retrieve me more index I don't know why. Another way is to divide each query, if I have 30 left outer join I divide for section the query. in terms of speed isn't a bad idea, what do you think?